# Kotlin: extension function vs member function with dispatch reciever

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has a `A.to(that: B)` extension function that takes any two types of parameter and return `Pair<A,B>`. Now I have a class with `to` function with takes two argments.

Basically the two different `to` functions have exact syntax and the function in the class is getting masked by the extension one.

**Example**:

```
// following return Pair<k,v>
fun convert(value:K, converter: org.jooq.Converter<K,V>) = converter.to(value)
```

Jooq converter is a fairly popular class to convert between Database compatible class to custom class.

According to Kotlin's [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), extension functions take priority over the class methods, which doesn't make sense for the extension methods provided by kotlin package as their scope is global. There is *[qualified-this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified)* workaround for outscoping the extension functions but it doesn't seem to be helping here

Edit: `fun convert` itself is an extension function. Otherwise the member function takes priority.

Comment: Actually for the topic "extension function vs member method" it's the reverse. From the doc: `If a class has a member function, and an extension function is defined which has the same receiver type, the same name and is applicable to given arguments, the member always wins`

Comment: Interstingly they also wrote it in the link I gave- "In case of a name conflict between the members of the dispatch receiver and the extension receiver, the extension receiver takes precedence. To refer to the member of the dispatch receiver you can use the qualified this syntax."

Comment: @user2340612 could you please, provide a reference link for the above statement.

Comment: that's interesting, I was not aware of that, but it makes sense: inside an extension function you want to call methods belonging to the type extended in priority w.r.t. other member functions. Concerning the link, actually it's in the same page you linked, just a few lines above the statement you quoted

Comment: So basically it happened because convert itself was a extension function!

Comment: yep, that might be the root cause :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types as stated in the question don't match: `Converter<K, V>.to` [takes `V`, not `K`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.9.0/org/jooq/Converter.html#to-U-). So `converter.to(value)` resolves to the extension method simply because it can't be the member method.

Of course, that means your own answer wouldn't work either; probably you modified some of the types, and if you try `converter.to(value)` now it should work.

Comment: Yup, I resolved that.  I changed method segnature to fun convert(value:V, converter: org.jooq.Converter<.,V>). You are right. Changing the code back to the original one. it worked. Thanks. I didn't notice that.